# Best way to create an intranet IP list database obtained from linux terminal (nbtscan or another command)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, csv, ip

How should I structure a database where I need to store the IP(as INT unsigned) address, sectors where they are being used and the name of the machine.
It will be used to quick search the available IP.
As is known that the addresses won't be more than 254 per network should I create a separated table with the list?

[Edit]

Another thing came to mind. If I already now that the networks will go from 192.168.x.1 to 192.168.x.254 and sometimes I would like to see which IP is free or which IP is set to a specific machine, should I fill the table with the addresses and later associate them creating a list with the used and the free ones?

[Edit]

After using nbtscan I think I can get the data I want.
The command

```
nbtscan 192.168.0.1-254 -t 20000
```

Gives me:

```
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from 192.168.0.1-254

IP address       NetBIOS Name     Server    User             MAC address      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.0.135    EREBOS           <server>  EREBOS           00-00-00-00-00-00
192.168.0.130    CHAOS                      <unknown>        00-00-00-00-00-00
```

A good result, but:

```
nbtscan -s , 192.168.0.1-254 -t 20000
```

Gives me:

```
192.168.0.130,CHAOS          ,,<unknown>,00-00-00-00-00-00
192.168.0.135,EREBOS         ,<server>,EREBOS         ,00-00-00-00-00-00
```

And now I am using:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=ips.csv');

include_once "conn.php";

$iprange = "192.168.0.1-254";
$timeout = 20000;
$separator = ",";

$strre = shell_exec("nbtscan -s $separator $iprange -t $timeout");
echo preg_replace('/ +/',',', $strre);
```

To generate a .csv file that I can import to MySQL.
Is that a good sollution?

I don't know why but nbtscan is giving different number of columns. The first line has 6 and the second 7. That is anoying! Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: You should probably just store it as a string field, and make it long enough to store ipv6 addresses. That way it's future-proof, and much easier to browse the data in the database. You can store IPV4 addresses with an unsigned int, but they are hard to look at in the database, and sometimes it's nice to be able to look at stuff in the database. You could even put a trigger on the table to ensure the IP address is properly formatted.  You probably aren't going to have enough addresses that storage space would be an issue.

Comment: For now I using two tables one with the IP addresses and another with the sectors. The machine name is in the IP table.

Comment: For now I using two tables one with the IP addresses and another with the sectors/places. The machine name is in the IP table.
I am storing IP as INT UNSIGNED. I am using INET_ATON(field_name) to insert data and INET_NTOA(field_name) to select data

Comment: That's what `nmap` does. nmap can scan a network and generate an XML file. But really, DHCP should be used and the DHCP server will know what is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the free IP address tracker from SolarWinds?

http://www.solarwinds.com/downloads/

I had used it before and it worked well for my needs. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thank you. But it is for Windows, for Linux would fit me best. And it needs .NET! Which means too much resources used.

Comment: @tenshimsm no problem, was unaware of the OS you were using.

Comment: :D My mistake. I should've mentioned that I want it to accessible through the intranet. A search system.